# converting apache rewrite to nginx url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

can anybody help me to convert .htacess file to nginx rewrite rule 
my htaccess blew

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\/$ /index.php?page=details&title=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?page=result&q=$1 [L]
```

i try apply on here:
 /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
# nginx configuration

location /video {
  rewrite ^/video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\/$ /index.php?page=details&title=$1&id=$2 break;
  rewrite ^/video/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?page=result&q=$1 break;
}
```

not working..

Comment: Use `last` instead of `break`.

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/rewrite

Comment: try but same result..