# How to Rewrite URL in Nginx in analogy with Apache's .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I have recently moved our website to AWS (Ubuntu, Nginx) from CentOS (Apache2).
Nginx doesn't support .htaccess so the URL rewriting isn't working on the website.

I have tried to convert the .htaccess codes to Nginx directives equivalent as follows:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^calories/(.*) _calories.php?fname=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^workouts/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ wdetails.php?wtype=$1&wname=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^workouts/([^/]+)?$ _workout.php?wtype=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^workouts?$ _workouts.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^workout-plans/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) workout-plans/_wdetails.php?wname=$1&wid=$2&day=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^workout-plans/(.*)/(.*) workout-plans/_wdays.php?wname=$1&wid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)/(.*) articles/article.php?aid=$1&aname=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^recipes/(.*)/(.*) recipes/recipe.php?rid=$1&rname=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^memes/(.*)/(.*) memes/meme.php?mid=$1&mname=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^quotes/(.*)/(.*) quotes/quote.php?qid=$1&qname=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^questions/(.*)/(.*) questions/question.php?qid=$1&qname=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^transformations/(.*)/(.*) transformations/transformation.php?tid=$1&tname=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)/(.*) posts/post.php?pid=$1&pname=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^tags/(.*)/(.*) tags/_tag.php?ptype=$1&tag=$2 [L]


Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

**Nginx Directives**

```
    error_page 404 /;

location / {
  if ($http_host !~ "^www\."){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://www.$http_host/$1 redirect;
  }
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/([^\.]+)$ /$1.php break;
  }
  rewrite ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 redirect;
  rewrite ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php break;
}

location /calories {
  rewrite ^/calories/(.*) /_calories.php?fname=$1 break;
}

location /workouts {
  rewrite ^/workouts/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /wdetails.php?wtype=$1&wname=$2 break;
  rewrite ^/workouts/([^/]+)?$ /_workout.php?wtype=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/workouts?$ /_workouts.php break;
}

location /workout {
  rewrite ^/workout-plans/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /workout-plans/_wdetails.php?wname=$1&wid=$2&day=$3 break;
  rewrite ^/workout-plans/(.*)/(.*) /workout-plans/_wdays.php?wname=$1&wid=$2 break;
}

location /articles {
  rewrite ^/articles/(.*)/(.*) /articles/article.php?aid=$1&aname=$2 break;
}

location /recipes {
  rewrite ^/recipes/(.*)/(.*) /recipes/recipe.php?rid=$1&rname=$2 break;
}

location /memes {
  rewrite ^/memes/(.*)/(.*) /memes/meme.php?mid=$1&mname=$2 break;
}

location /quotes {
  rewrite ^/quotes/(.*)/(.*) /quotes/quote.php?qid=$1&qname=$2 break;
}

location /questions {
  rewrite ^/questions/(.*)/(.*) /questions/question.php?qid=$1&qname=$2 break;
}

location /transformations {
  rewrite ^/transformations/(.*)/(.*) /transformations/transformation.php?tid=$1&tname=$2 break;
}

location /posts {
  rewrite ^/posts/(.*)/(.*) /posts/post.php?pid=$1&pname=$2 break;
}

location /tags {
  rewrite ^/tags/(.*)/(.*) /tags/_tag.php?ptype=$1&tag=$2 break;
}
```

Yet the custom URL rewrites don't work. Only the folders & files without .php extension work fine.
What am I doing wrong? How to fix this?

**Note**: I used an online tool to convert the .htaccess code to Nginx Directives.

Also, have a look into this: [converting apache rewrite to nginx url rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223080/converting-apache-rewrite-to-nginx-url-rewrite)

Comment: Use `rewrite...last` instead of `rewrite...break` when the rewritten URI must be processed by another `location`.

Comment: @RichardSmith changing `break` to last `last` solved most URL issues except for the type: `/articles/articlelist?p=1` URLs. Can you post an answer with the solution to it?